# Unable to schedule python script using crontab

Tags: python, python-3.x, cron, centos, scheduler

I am trying to schedule a python script using crontab to run every three minutes. It's not executing as per schedule set.

When I try to execute the script from the centos terminal it's working properly. How to fix this.

**Location of my script**

/opt/app-root/src/S3_Upload_V1.py

**Location of crontab**
/usr/bin/crontab

**My  scheduling code**

```
*/3 * * * * /opt/app-root/src/S3_Upload_V1.py
```

The script executes independently from the terminal but not from the crontab schedule. How to fix this?

[image]

Comment: Trivial typo: you have a space between `*` and `/3`.

Comment: @tripleee, I dont space. Its a typo.I corrected it now

Comment: More generally, you are expected to perform basic troubleshooting before posting. The nominated dupicate and [the Stack Overflow `crontab` tag info page](/tags/crontab/info) show how. If this is one of the common cases, please accept the duplicate nomination.

Comment: ,.. And if not, please [edit] your question to include useful diagnotics, i.e. that you have checked the regular logs and your email inbox; you get an error message somewhere, we need to see it.

Comment: @ashokeapen  I SEE that you took my advice to use `cron` as cited in my answer to your previous question on using `schedule` to execute a script -- every workday (monday to friday) at 8 PM CET.

Answer (score 0):

A possible cause can be the permissions. You should make sure the file has execution permission. You can do this by running the following:

```sh
chmod u+x /opt/app-root/src/S3_Upload.py
```

You Should also make sure there is a "shebang" (`#!`) in the beginning of your script:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

Comment: I added the '#!' in the begining of the script still is not executing. Also I appened the question showing the permission rights

Comment: Try executing it using the full path and see if there is any issues: ```./opt/app-root/src/S3_Upload.py```

Comment: By the way, the screenshot you just included shows a script with a different file name then the code you provided...

Comment: i just modified the script to append '#!'

Comment: Bubble Hacker, still doesnt work

Comment: Can you check if the script you are actually trying to run is named ```S3_Upload.py``` or ```S3_Upload_V1.py```?

Comment: Its S3_Upload_V1. I have checked and included all the changes you have said. still not running

Comment: So now the cron tab looks like this: ```*/3 * * * * /opt/app-root/src/S3_Upload_V1.py```?

Comment: Yes .you are correct

Comment: And can you tell me which version of Python you are using on your OS?

Comment: Its Python 3.6.3

Comment: Can you also locate where Python is installed? I am asking this because Python may be installed in a different location than the default which means you will need to change the path in the ```#!```

Comment: Python is installed in  /opt/app-root/bin/python.  I have added this location inside the script  #!/opt/app-root/bin/python3